# Remover quebra de linha após cada INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo um `textarea` em meu código, onde o usuário vai inserir vouchers de acesso separados por ENTER.

O meu código PHP trata os valores digitados da seguinte forma:

```
$voucher = explode("\n",$voucher);
      foreach ($voucher as &$varray)
      {
        $gravar = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `vouchers` (voucher, tempo) VALUES ('$varray','$tempoBD')");
      }
```

Onde: `$voucher` é o valor do textarea recebido via `$_POST` e `$tempoBD` é o valor que o usuário selecionar convertido no formato `00:00:00`.

O problema é: O campo voucher está salvando o valor da linha + quebra de linha (`\n`)!

Qual a correção no meu código preciso fazer para que seja removida a quebra de linha no campo voucher a cada registro inserido na tabela?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o strip_tags junto do trim, o strip_tags vai remover qualquer codigo html ou php do seu arquivo e o trim vai remover os espaços do inicio e do fim.

```
$voucher = explode("\n",$voucher);
foreach ($voucher as &$varray){
    $formata = strip_tags(trim($varray));
    $gravar = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `vouchers` (voucher, tempo) VALUES ('".$formata."','$tempoBD')");
}
```

Comment: Mas dessa forma não resolve meu problema, pois se trata de um textarea, conforme expliquei na pergunta. Preciso tratar cada linha como um registro no banco

Comment: Tente agora @JhonatanJunio

Comment: AGORA SIM! hehehe; Muito obrigado, @Lucas Carvalho! Resolveu o meu problema. Não conhecia  o strip_tags. Salvou mesmo, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Use o `trim()` para remover as quebra de linhas.

```
$voucher = explode("\n",$voucher);
foreach ($voucher as &$varray){
    $gravar = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `vouchers` (voucher, tempo) VALUES ('".trim($varray)."','$tempoBD')");
}
```

Comment: É, sua resposta está melhor mesmo. Pôs ele precisa pegar os espaços, entendi!

Comment: Devo estar fazendo algo errado.. Está salvando no banco como {trim( + valor da linha + )}. Vou tentar corrigir a sintaxe aqui

Comment: Cara, a sintaxe eu resolvi. O problema é que continuou salvando com uma quebra de linha no banco! Se eu dou o comando UPDATE vouchers  SET voucher = TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(voucher, CHAR(13),''), CHAR(10),'')) no banco, ele altera os registros. Consegue me ajudar?

Comment: @JhonatanJunio tem certeza que é quebra de linha? o `trim()` deveria resolver. Não é um `<BR>`?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho crase vai em nomes de tabelas, views, campos identificadores em geral é o caracter de escape. Aspas simples só vai em valores.

Comment: Não sabia disso, na verdade nunca usei. Obrigado rray

Comment: Tenho, @rray .. É que nem falei, estou pegando os valores de um textarea e quebrando os ENTER com o \n. No banco está vindo o valor do campo+uma quebra de linha. No HeidiSQL ele até diz "Quebra de linha Mac OS detectada"